# Magento 2 : How to Create Recent Orders Block on CMS Page or Static Block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, cms-pages

I want to call block on the home page of the store. how can I add recent order block on store home page from admin? Thanks

I have tried this `<p>{{block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent" template="Magento_Sales::order/recent.phtml"}}</p>`
Thanks

Comment: The block you are using would only show recent order of currently logged in customer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Because without login we can not access store home page.

Comment: Then your code should work. what issue you are facing?

Comment: Blank page showing. Any other way is there?

Comment: This is not the error, please check exception.log for actual error

Comment: Nothing in var/log

Comment: if you are using it on server then check server error log. You can also check error on browser if you are on developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation`

Comment: Nothing is there.